# Upgrading to flutter 3.0

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies

I am severely getting error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- Where:
  Script '~\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1156
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

  `'~/flutter\bin\flutter.bat' finished with non-zero exit value 1`

Currently I am using flutter 2.10.4. Waiting to upgrade with newer version but unfortunately gone few days because of work.

Tried deleting cache and build files. Clean and rebuild the project, nothing works. 
Any help would be a great support!

Comment: You need to upgrade your packages.
Above this error there will be some warnings from the packages you are using.
Check which packages are giving the error and try to upgrade those packages to the latest version, if updates for those packages are available, if not you can skip upgrading that package.
Then build and it should work. I faced the same problem when I upgraded my Flutter version from 2.10.4 to 3.0.3 recently

Comment: Used command: 
`flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. 
Gradle updated, but didn't even work!

Comment: That will not upgrade the dependencies in the pubspec.yaml file, it would only update the pubspec.lock file. So you meed to manually update each package in pubspec.yaml file which is giving the warnings